# Complexity of the simplex algorithm

Tags: ds.algorithms, linear-programming, simplex, smoothed-analysis

What is the upper bound on the simplex algorithm for finding a solution to a Linear Program?

How would I go about finding a proof for such a case?
It seems as though the worst case is if each vertex has to be visited that is it $O(2^n)$. However in practice the simplex algorithm will run significantly faster than this for more standard problems.

How can I reason about the average complexity of a problem being solved using this method?

Any information or references are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Note that, as mashca said in an [answer](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2373/complexity-of-simplex-algorithm/2377#2377), we do not really have “the simplex algorithm.”  There are many different simplex algorithms depending on the choice of a pivoting rule.

Comment: A cube in dimension $n$ has $2^n$ vertices, and so this if an upper bound for any simplex variant on (e.g., Klee-Minty) cubes. However, there are polyhedra in dimension $n$ with $2n$ facets, such as dual cyclic polytopes, with more than $2^n$ vertices, so $2^n$ is not an immediate upper bound of for the running time of the simplex method for square constraint matrices in general.

Answer (score 83):

The simplex algorithm indeed visits all $2^n$ vertices in the worst case ([Klee & Minty 1972](https://ci.nii.ac.jp/naid/10020194052/)), and this turns out to be true for any deterministic pivot rule. However, in a landmark paper using a smoothed analysis, Spielman and Teng (2001) [proved](http://arxiv.org/abs/cs.DS/0111050) that when the inputs to the algorithm are slightly randomly perturbed, the expected running time of the simplex algorithm is polynomial for any inputs -- this basically says that for any problem there is a "nearby" one that the simplex method will efficiently solve, and it pretty much covers every real-world linear program you'd like to solve.  Afterwards, Kelner and Spielman (2006) [introduced](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/spielman/Research/SimplexStoc.pdf) a polynomial time randomized simplex algorithm that truley works on any inputs, even the bad ones for the original simplex algorithm.

Answer (score 38):

As Lev said, in the worst case the algorithm visits all $2^d$ vertices where $d$ is number of variables. However, the performance of the simplex algorithm may also greatly depend on the specific pivot rule used. As far as I am aware, it is still an open question if there exists a specific deterministic pivot rule with sub-exponential worst-case running time. Many candidates have been ruled out by lower bound results. Recently, [Friedmann, Hansen, and Zwick](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/1.9781611973082.19) also showed the first non-polynomial lower bounds for some natural randomized pivot rules with some corrections provided [later](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.7871.pdf).

However, adding to the smoothed analysis result mentioned by Lev: Following Spielman and Tengs seminal paper introducing smoothed analysis, Vershynin [improved](https://www.math.uci.edu/~rvershyn/papers/simplex-journal.pdf) their bounds further in 2006. He showed that the expected running time on slightly perturbed instances is only poly-logarithmic in the number of constraints $n$, down from $n^{86}$.

Comment: and as JeffE pointed out in a different question (http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2149/consequences-of-existence-of-a-strongly-polynomial-algorithm-for-linear-programmi) the current best subexponential method is a kind of dual simplex.

Comment: The link to the Vershynin paper is dead.

Answer (score 9):

To obtain insight into the worst-case and average-case analysis of the simplex method, you should read "Smoothed Analysis: Why The Simplex Algorithm Usually Takes Polynomial Time." by Spielman and Teng.

Answer (score 3):

A good reference on why simplex is not running in polynomial time, rather than why it's exponential is Papadimitriou & Steiglitz Combinatorial Optimization, Section 8.6 in which they demonstrate that Simplex is not a polynomial-time algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

In 2019, the opensource LP solver [GLPK](https://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/) 
does the
[Klee-Minty cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klee-Minty_cube)
problem with $D=200$
in under 100 milliseconds, on a 2.7 GHz iMac:

```
GLPK Simplex Optimizer, v4.65
200 rows, 200 columns, 20100 non-zeros
Preprocessing...
199 rows, 200 columns, 20099 non-zeros
Scaling...
 A: min|aij| =  1.000e+00  max|aij| =  1.607e+60  ratio =  1.607e+60
...
Constructing initial basis...
Size of triangular part is 199
*     0: obj =   0.000000000e+00 inf =   0.000e+00 (200)
*     1: obj = -6.223015278e+139 inf =   0.000e+00 (0)
OPTIMAL LP SOLUTION FOUND
Time used:   0.0 secs
Memory used: 3.4 Mb
```

Can anyone suggest other ways to construct difficult problems for the simplex method,
slow but not memory-bound ?

Added: Latin squares aka [3d-permutation-matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3370934/3d-permutation-matrices) seem to have many vertices -- how many ?
<sub>Theory and practice are closer in theory than they are in practice.</sub>

Answer (score -3):

it might be a bit off-topic but even the interior-point methods do have an exponential worst-case complexity as proven in the following paper:
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10107-006-0044-x#citeas

so basically Linear Programming has an exponential worst-case complexity or am I getting this wrong?

Comment: Linear programming is in P.  Even some interior-point methods (e.g. Karmarkar's algorithm) have poly-time bounds(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karmarkar%27s_algorithm)  And of course the Ellipsoid method takes polynomial time.

Comment: Yes, you are wrong. The running time is to be measured as a function of the (bit)length of the input. Here both are exponential in the parameter $n$.

Comment: @neal Young they just have poly-time bounds on regular problems though? Have you looked into the article?

Comment: do you guys know a complexity comparison of different methods for solving LP by any chance?