# Is it possible to approximate the solution of NP-Hard problems in polynomial time using linear programming?

Tags: np-hardness, approximation-algorithms, optimization, linear-programming, approximation-hardness

Suppose we have a `NP-Hard` problem such as the `k-col`, which is meant to determine if a graph may be colored using at most `k` different colors.

Considering we model the `k-col` problem as a `linear programming` problem, then apply slightly random perturbations ([Spielman and Teng - 2001](https://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0111050)) to the input tableau for the `simplex` algorithm as mentioned [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2373/complexity-of-the-simplex-algorithm), obtaining a problem very close to the original one:

1. may it be solved in polynomial time ?
2. in practice, may it be solved optimally for a huge graph (1k vertices or more) or would the solution be a near-optimum ?

PS:
Please, note I have considered [this](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/17601/smoothed-analysis-of-approximation-algorithms) before posting this question, however, I still didn't understand, therefore, I would like to see an answer in simpler words. In addition, I'm not sure if `smoothed analysis` is related to the questions I've asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what algorithm you suggest, but in general it is known there are many NP-hard problems that are also NP-hard to approximate. So I don't think this line of attacking NP-hard problems is going to lead you to success in polynomial time.

I suggest looking through https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~luca/pcp/ if you are curious for more information in this direction.